# How to modify slices using pointers

Tags: go

Why isn't the slice being modified in the following code:

```
package pointers

import "fmt"

func modifyObject(v *Vertex) {
    v.x = v.x * v.x
    v.y = v.y * v.y
}

func modifyArray(vertices *[]Vertex) {
    for _, v := range *vertices {
        v.x = v.x * v.x
        v.y = v.y * v.y
    }
}

func DemoPointersArray() {
    v := Vertex{2, 3}
    modifyObject(&v)
    fmt.Println("Vertex modified successfully:", v)

    v1 := Vertex{2, 3}
    v2 := Vertex{20, 30}
    vertices := []Vertex{v1, v2}
    modifyArray(&vertices)
    fmt.Println("Vertices are NOT modified:", vertices)
}
```

*Output:*
Vertex modified successfully: {4 9}
Vertices are NOT modified: [{2 3} {20 30}]

How to modify them?

Comment: The question initially was 'How to modify arrays using pointers?'. It was changed to 'How to modify slices using pointers?' by users answering the question. My bulb went on as soon as I saw it. It is an 'array'  only when a size is declared. For e.g. vertices := [2]Vertex{v1, v2}. Otherwise, they are all slices e.g: vertices := []Vertex{v1, v2}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `modifyArray` modifies the local variable `v`, not the slice element. Assign to the slice element using an index expression:

```
func modifyArray(vertices *[]Vertex) {
    for i, v := range *vertices {
        (*vertices)[i].x = v.x * v.x
        (*vertices)[i].y = v.y * v.y
    }
}
```

Because the slice contains a pointer to the backing array, there's no need to pass a pointer to the slice:

```
func modifyArray(vertices []Vertex) {
    for i, v := range vertices {
        vertices[i].x = v.x * v.x
        vertices[i].y = v.y * v.y
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
modifyArray(vertices)  // do not take address of vertices
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/6W5Wwb2p9oV)

You can use `modifyObject` by taking the address of the slice element:

```
 func modifyArray(vertices []Vertex) {
    for i := range vertices {
        modifyObject(&vertices[i])
    }
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/RF3kXTMnLr5)

Unlike other answers, this answer retains the memory layout in the question.

Answer (score 7):

In your second example you are passing a pointer to a slice.  There is almost never a reason to do that as the slice is already a pointer to an array (along with a length and capacity).

[image]  [image]

Your pointer to a slice contains instances of Vertex, not *Vertex, so modifying them does not have any affect.  If you instead changed your method signature to

```
func modifyArray(vertices []*Vertex)
```

and passed a slice of pointers, then you could modify them like you expect.

Here is a [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NP_2uYDVQdl) showing you by example.  The corresponding code is below

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Vertex struct {
    x int
    y int
}

func modifyObject(v *Vertex) {
    v.x = v.x * v.x
    v.y = v.y * v.y
}

func modifyArray(vertices []*Vertex) {
    for _, v := range vertices {
        v.x = v.x * v.x
        v.y = v.y * v.y
    }
}

func main() {
    v := Vertex{2, 3}
    modifyObject(&v)
    fmt.Println("Vertex modified successfully:", v)

    v1 := Vertex{2, 3}
    v2 := Vertex{20, 30}
    vertices := []*Vertex{&v1, &v2}
    modifyArray(vertices)
    fmt.Printf("Vertices are modified: %v %v", vertices[0], vertices[1])
}
```